# Rails 7: Kaminari data list modified and not recognized for pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem. I successfully implemented the Kaminari pagination using the following code in my controller:

```
def index
    users = User.order(:creation_date).reverse_order.page(params[:page])

    # Filter users
    users = users.where(gender: params[:gender]) if params[:gender]
    users = users.where(job: params[:job]) if params[:job]
    users = users.where(car: params[:car]) if params[:car]

    @users = users
end
```

But now I added a class which modifies some data parts in the user. This method returns the same users list, but with the modified data, but after that, I get this error in my webapp:

```
undefined method `total_pages'
```

I understand that this new returned list isn't a kaminari data list, because it lost the `page` method that I put on it in the first query, but when I try to put it on the new list, I get this:

```
undefined method `page'
```

This line is added after the filters in the controller:

```
users = Scanner::Origin.calculate(users)
```

So I have tried adding `users = users.page(params[:page]).per(20)` below the new line, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas how to fix the pagination with this new data?

Comment: `page` is just a query method, you can call it on a model or relation object, like you do with `where`. `.page(1)` is a shortcut for `.limit(25).offset(0)` and it [adds](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/v1.2.2/kaminari-activerecord/lib/kaminari/activerecord/active_record_model_extension.rb#L17) all the other pagination methods to the current relation object. so if `calculate` returns something  else, probably an array, you're losing pagination functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
def index
  users = User.order(creation_date: :desc).page(params[:page])

...
```

Comment: Yeah, I already have .page on the first query, which is working fine. The problem is after this line `users = Scanner::Origin.calculate(users)` the pagination stops working. After adding this line to my code, the `users` list doesn't have the pagination anymore

Comment: Yes, I meant remove the `reverse_order` and replace with  `.order(creation_date: :desc)'.  Doesn't that fix it?

Comment: Oh sorry, but nope.. Still same error: `undefined method 'total_pages'`

Comment: OK what is `Scanner::Origin`. What type of object does it return.  You need it to return a scope or maybe do pagination without Kaminari.

Comment: Okay, I know why I get this error. I am resorting the list in the `calculate` method. The pagination is working now!

Comment: Your sorting helped as well!